# BizTalk Documenter - Object Reference Error

Tags: biztalk

I've just installed documenter onto a BizTalk 2016 Dev VM after download the msi from GitHub at: https://github.com/mbrimble/biztalkdocumenter

I run the exe from the start menu shortcut as admin. When I click the "Generate Documentation" button, the progress bar promotes 3 squares before an exception dialog titled "Error Generating Documentation" is displayed. This contains the message "Object reference not set to instance of an object"

I've reduced scope to a single  very simple BizTalk application.
I've tried output options of "Compiled Help" and "Word 2003 Xml" but same problem.

[image: ObjectRefError]

Comment: You might have to download the source code and re-compile, as that version was probably compiled against .Net 4.5     There was also a prerequisite of HTML Help Workshop.   I though we had disabled the Word output, as that was out of date anyway.

Comment: After updating the projects to use .Net 4.6 it did compile and run ok. I've raised a pull request on the github project. @Dijkgraaf if you provide as answer I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to download the source code and re-compile, as that version was compiled against .Net 4.5